# Дублирование страниц, SEO, Wordpress

Tags: seo

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, если у меня будут повторяться страницы с одинаковым названием, но с разным содержимым, может ли это как то повлиять на СЕО? Или как можно решить вопрос?

Comment: https://livepage.pro/knowledge-base/duplicate-pages.html вот тут об этом большая подробная статья и методы решения.

Comment: Хорошо, а если у меня сайт изначально без индексации полностью и у меня есть две одинаковые страницы: Платья и Платья-2, и при этом они имеют разные url : домен/платья и домен/платья-2, то это всё равно может плохо повлиять на СЕО? При том , что даже разный контент внутри из каждой страницы

Comment: Дак вы определитесь, у вас разные страницы или одинаковые. Разный контент = разные страницы.

Comment: Да, получается я иммел ввиду страницы с полностью одинаковым названием (Платья), но url у них разный - Платья и Платья 2, виноват, то есть по идеи никак не должно влиять на СЕО в таком случаи, правильно?

Comment: Если у вас некоторый набор страниц с разными URL (/platie/, /superplatie/, /platie?page=1) но с абсолютно одинаковым содержанием (ну т.е. весь контент одинаковый) - это проблема которую надо решать. Почему это проблема и методы решения описаны в статье. Если у вас просто <title></title> у них одинаковый, а контент отличается, то это просто не хорошо и крайне не рекомендуется.

Comment: Хорошо, у меня просто title одинаковый, но как же решить проблему эту? Я не могу написать по другому и в той ссылке на решение, которую Вы дали, я не смог найти ответа, там нужно создавать сайт на разных поддоменах, но разве это единственное решение? От индексации я тоже не могу закрыть одну из этих title

Comment: Придумать разные Title. Платье можем быть "Красивое" "Красное" "для девочек"

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, у меня есть мега меню из женской одежды, которое разделяется на "ОДЕЖДА" и "БОЛЬШИЕ РАЗМЕРЫ", в каждой из под этих главных заголовков идут ссылки: Платье, Пальто и т.д., получается я могу добавить Платье + или Платье + SIZE в "БОЛЬШИЕ РАЗМЕРЫ" и тогда СЕО ругаться не будет, верно? Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Можно еще производителя добавить. Просто возьмите за правило, что каждая страница должна иметь уникальный Title, H1 тэг и description. После того как сайт заработает добавьте его в яндекс вебмастер и он через какое-то время выдаст вам все ваши "ошибки" по SEO.

Comment: Но ошибку мне не выдаст, если у меня будет Платье + SIZE у которого другой description и соответсвенно h1 тэг, кстати по поводу h1 тэга, могут ли конфликтовать страницы в Мега меню? У них же по факту у всех H1 тэг, т.к. это страницы или по идеи всё нормально тоже должно быть?

Comment: h1 на странице должен быть один. Сделайте в меню h2-h6 теги, их может быть сколько угодно.

Comment: Ну я через ctrl + u посмотрел и там пока что нету h1 вовсе, т.к. еще не отредактирована страница, получается h1 только то, чья эта страница и изменять пока что ничего не нужно, коль не показывают в ctrl + u эти остальные страницы

Answer (score 0):

Каждая веб-страницы является документом (для точности - HTML документом). Каждый документ имеет субъект (тему) содержания. Разное содержание документа подразумевает и сепаратный субъект содержания. Например, платья являются именем категории верхней женской одежды. Если взглянуть на уровень ниже в этой категории, то там мы можем обнаружить платья летние, платья теплые, свадебные платья, платья вечерние и так далее. Если смотреть например на определенную категорию, такую как Платья  вечерние, то там можно обнаружить также множество вариантов по цвету, по модели,  по бренду и так далее.

Все эти индивидуальные особенности платьев могут быть частями субъекта содержания. Например, платье вечернее, из набивного льна, темно серого цвета (имеются следующие цветовые варианты....), обтягивающее, от Версачи.

Ваша задача является нахождения точного субъекта для каждого сепаратного содержания, которое явно идентифицирует объект содержания на уровне веб-сайта. Другими словами каждый объект содержания и представление объекта в теме содержания должны быть уникальны на уровне вашего веб-сайта. Хорошим примером может быть содержание веб-сайта представляющего запасные части для автомобилей или автобусов. Там каждая запасная часть имеет индивидуальное отличие от других частей, хотя все они являются частями автомобилей или автобусов. Тоже самое можно применять и к платьям и к любым продуктам и товарам.